# AssertionError at hours_ahead

Tags: django, assertion

When i use assert false method,i get error :

```
assertionError at /time/plus/2/
No exception supplied
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/time/plus/2/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Location: C:\my\my\views.py in hours_ahead, line 18
```

Here is my code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
import datetime

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>it is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)

def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
           raise Http404()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    assert False
    html = "<html><body>In %s hours,it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I write code that is in The definite guide to django part2 .But it get error and i can`t understand what it is bad in this code.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assert False always throws an exception, it's meant for testing. [more information on testing here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#writing-tests)

I suppose you can just remove that line and your function should work as expected.

Comment: Yes,when it`s removed it work perfect,but when i add assert false it create an error.In that book code are with assert false and it is good ,maybe this is for new django version?